# Typescript: merging types to one SUPER type. What is best practise?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following defined types:

```
export type Cartesian2DCoordinate = {
  x: number,
  y: number
};

export type EquatorialCoordinate = {
  az: number,
  alt: number,
};
```

I also have the following type defined:

```
export type PolarCoordinate = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  az: number;
  alt: number;
};
```

However, is there a simpler way to merge the `Cartesian2DCoordinate` and `EquatorialCoordinate` types as a "super type" or is it better practise to make a type on the fly where it's needed?

It's just not clear in my mind from my understanding of the typescript docs...

In terms of intersections, would this be an acceptable "**do**":

```
export type Cartesian2DCoordinate = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};

export type Cartesian3DCoordinate = Cartesian2DCoordinate & {
  z: number;
}
```

Comment: An acceptable "**do**"? It's one way of modelling `Cartesian3DCoordinate`, yes... However, I'd probably be explicit here if only to remove barriers to others understanding my code. If I want to see what a `Cartesian3DCoordinate` is, it's a 2 step job... However, there's no hard&fast rules on this and, because TypeScript is [*structurally* typed](https://medium.com/redox-techblog/structural-typing-in-typescript-4b89f21d6004) you can be fairly lax about this to no ill-effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading it right, you can just create an intersection of the two types:

```
type PolarCoordinate = Cartesian2DCoordinate & EquatorialCoordinate;
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types

Comment: Ok, a quick Goolge of intersections in typescript gave me an outdated doc page which has been superceeded by this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types but there's scant to brief mention of intersections...

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts I added a [docs link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)

Comment: Ahh yes, different doc page now - gah! Nightmare sometimes. Would it be better practise to do the above intersection on the fly, so something like this: `someFunctionWhichReturnsIntersection(): Cartesian2DCoordinate & EquatorialCoordinate { ... };` *Bearing in mind really the above structure is not really a physical variable in the subject topic I'm working on ... it's more of a mashup type. Also, should this be a type or an interface?

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts It took me a while to find, so I can see how you missed it. If it's going to save you some typing, why not declare the intersection type explicitly? I don't really have a preference, but if it's popping up in loads of different places, make a new type to serve as an alias to stave-off the RSI :) I'm still to find a reasonable difference between types and interfaces unless deep-diving into the type system. Once again, no real preference, but you won't be able to make an intersection interface.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise. At the moment - the intersection pops up once, in my brain - if it was some sort of model inheritance I would go for intersection and a new type. But for me, because it's merging two different physical variables - I'm prefering not intersecting. I've added an example of where an intersection would make more sense, so thanks for helping on that. From what I've done, I've created an intersection between a defined type and a type defined on the fly ... I feel this is bad practise.